# Checking the following series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{4\sqrt{n}}\frac{(16n-4)}{\sqrt{16n+64}}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck trying to check if the following series is convergent:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{4\sqrt{n}}\frac{(16n-4)}{\sqrt{16n+64}}
$$
I tried to use Leibniz‏ theorem but without any success. Is is possible to show how to prove it?

Comment: well the numerator is $O(n)$ while the denominator is $O(\sqrt n) * O(\sqrt n) = O(n)$ so before you even start to check you can already know that the sequence behaves like $O(1)$ so the series must diverge. So instead of checking blindly you can use some method to try and prove that it's divergent (hint: since it's $O(1)$, it means that the sequence does not approach 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary condition for the convergence of a series
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {a_n } 
$$
is that 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } a_n  = 0
$$
Since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}
{{4\sqrt n }}\frac{{16n - 4}}
{{\sqrt {16n + 64} }} = 1
$$
we have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } a_n  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( { - 1} \right)^n \frac{1}
{{4\sqrt n }}\frac{{16n - 4}}
{{\sqrt {16n + 64} }}
$$
does not exists and the series is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do the terms go to $0$?